# Should commits be automatically transferred when proposals are merged?

Tags: discussion, commitment, uncommit, area-51

I had committed to the selenium proposal, which was recently merged into a more general testing proposal.  Without clarifying my wishes, my commitment was transferred to the new proposal.  I actually would not commit to the more general proposal for various reasons, but because it immediately went into beta, I don't think I can withdraw my commitment.

I don't think people's intentions should be read into in this way.  If you want to merge the proposals, that's fine.  You then need to ensure everyone commits to the new proposal, not take it for granted that they will.

Comment: You can withdraw your commitment by logging into Area 51 and clicking the Uncommit button on the proposal page.

Answer (score 2):

When the proposals were merged, we contacted the participants of the original proposal specifically to give them the opportunity to *opt out* if they were no longer interested in the site.

The [Softare Quality Assurance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241/software-quality-assurance-testing) proposal has not been launched, yet. You can withdraw your commitment by visiting the proposal and clicking 'uncommit'.

Comment: There's nothing in the email about opting out. It simply says, "This is what we've decided to do... We hope it suits you."